# Count contours in python in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, count

I have a problem with a python program where I want to count the coins from the following example in C converting it to python.

[Coins contours](http://bsd-noobz.com/opencv-guide/60-1-counting-coins-in-an-image)

So far I was not able to find an equivalent for the C line:

```
sprintf(msg, "Found %d coins.", contours.size());
```

My main problem is with 'contours.size()', I tried to replace that code with len(), but it gives me a number of 154 instead of 4, see code below:

```
contours = cv.FindContours(cv.CloneImage(image_threshed), cv.CreateMemStorage(0), cv.CV_RETR_LIST, cv.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv.DrawContours(image, contours, cv.RGB(255,0,0), cv.RGB(0,255,55), 2,1,8)

NumeroContornos = str(len(contours))

font = cv.InitFont(cv.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .5, .5, 0, 1, 8)
cv.PutText(image,NumeroContornos, (5,17),font, cv.RGB(250,0,0))
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: That#s clearly not C, but C++ code. Different languages. OpenCV does not support C (anymore).

Answer (score 2):

When you find contours using cv.FindContours function, it returns you a cvSeq object. It returns multiple linked sequences, and you have to iterate through them to get all the contours.

So at first, the pointer points to first contour only, say your first coin. When you use `len(contour)`, it returns you the points inside that contour only, ie points of your first coin. So now you can imagine how you got 154. It is not number of contours, it is the number of points inside that contour. To see these points, `print list(contour)` and when you draw these points on the image, you can see it all constitutes the boundary of a coin.

Now to select the next contour, or next coin, use `contour = contour.h_next()` and so on.

I think there is no in-built function to return the number of contours, except you iterate through the contours and count it.

Try this and check if it prints 4 cvSeq objects :

```
while contours:
    print contours
    contours = contours.h_next()
```

I have explained all these things here : [What does result of 'list(contour)' denote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060254/what-does-result-of-listcontour-denote)

Instead, I would recommend you to use new `cv2` interface which is a lot simpler and better. There, contours are returned as list of Numpy arrays and you can use len(contour) to find the number of contours.

You can find brief description of differences between cv and cv2 here : [What is different between all these OpenCV Python interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417108/what-is-different-between-all-these-opencv-python-interfaces/10425504)

Old `cv` interface is going to be obsolete soon. So better migrate to new `cv2` interface.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I am learning python and opencv but certainly I will start using cv2, so my next task is to change the current program to cv2.

Comment: You will find it more interesting. Visit : www.opencvpython.blogspot.com for some beginning tutorials.

Comment: Also if it solves the problem, you can accept this answer by clicking on the tick mark near the answer and close this session.