# Get 1 contour per sign through find_contour and retrieve its Humoments in cv2

Tags: image-processing, opencv, python-2.7, contour, feature-extraction

It is possible obtain only 5 objects (one per sign) by applying find_contour (opencv module) in this image: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByS6Z5WRz-h2WHEzNnJucDlRR2s/edit ?
Now I obtain 64 objects

After that I want to retrieve Humoments and make a comparison with other images.
For now i'd try only with the same image a little bit translated, for testing it returns they are the same.

My question I how can I obtain only 5 objects for applying humoments or if there are other solutions to calculate humoments fot the image?

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('Sassatelli 1984 n. 165 mod1.jpg')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgray, (0,0), 5) 
cv2.imshow('Blur', blur)
cv2.waitKey()
th = 20
edges = cv2.Canny(blur, th, th*3)
cv2.imshow('canny',edges)
cv2.waitKey()
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print('objects found')
print(len(contours))
cnt = contours[0]
cv2.drawContours(blur,contours,-1,(0,255,0),3)
cv2.imshow('draw contours',blur)
cv2.waitKey()
moments = cv2.moments(cnt)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case 1: Problem with saving image in jpg format**
When you save a black-and-white-only (ie pixel values 0 and 255 only) image in jpg format, there is lossy compression, which changes the pixel values. If you want to see it, create such an image, save it in jpg, open the saved image and zoom to black-white edge. You can see a pixel value change.

So when you find contours, you expect there is only white objects, but in reality, there is some mid-values also, which is also considered as contours. It increases number of contours.

So to avoid this problem,

- Better save images in png or any other lossless format etc.
- Apply a threshold, (with a values of 127 or as you like) to make image real binary one before finding contours.

This is much more explained here : [What does result of 'list(contour)' denote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060254/what-does-result-of-listcontour-denote)

**Case 2: Problem with white background**

OpenCV findcontours() is designed to find white objects in black background. So if your background is white, it is also treated as one object. So invert the image before finding contours.

**Case 3 : Problem with holes in objects**

If you have holes in your object, it is also considered as an object. So if you want only external boundary of the objects, use `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` flag for findcontours() function.

**Sample Code:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('sof.jpg')
gray = cv2.imread('sof.jpg',0)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

**thresholded and inverted image** :

[image]

Now find the contours, draw it, check the number of contours:

```
cv2.drawContours(img,contours,-1,(0,255,0),2)
cv2.imshow('img',img),cv2.waitKey(0),cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Result :**

[image]

**NOTE :**

Here, I have taken only external contours. If you want to remove internal holes from these objects, you will need to use cv2.RETR_TREE or cv2.RETR_CCOMP flags, and check their hierarchy, and remove them. It is explained in this link : [Contours 5 : Hierarchy](http://opencvpython.blogspot.in/2013/01/contours-5-hierarchy.html)

Comment: thank you for your answer! I tried with these other 3 images converted in png format and i have some problem.  Image with big circle retrieve only 2 contours (i think because i choose RETR_EXTERNAL), Veio image 89 contours and the last 16 contours.                                          https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByS6Z5WRz-h2V2w4SFNXcVI5WFU/edit  https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByS6Z5WRz-h2cE1wTGJwRnE5YUU/edit https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByS6Z5WRz-h2bW9XTHU2TEtWSDA/edit

Comment: My question is if it's possible making adaptation also for these cases (i have many photos) or every image has to be analyzed in a different way. I told you that because i would like to compare this signs basing on humoments!

Comment: i forgot also this image: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByS6Z5WRz-h2UTFCaVEzaHlXRVk/edit. where it finds 36 objects, and so i think it finds also little dots (noise) without importance!

Comment: There are some "problems" with the images you added. ie the object is not continuous. If you zoom and view closely, you can see there are breaks in the objects boundary. in some places, these boundaries are cut into small pieces. It increases the number of contours.You can apply morphological operations like `erosion,dilation,closing` etc. I am not sure how much it will help.    Also, there are some noises in the image. It causes small little dots. You can use `cv2.contourArea()` to find contour area and take only those contours which have some minimum area.

Comment: it is possible (after applying a minimum contour area)  "adding" all contours and treat them like a unique contour (maybe if a contour is near to another contour in a pixel range? Or it's better find a new way to identify these signs?